# Using Xamarin to publish ASP.NET Site

Tags: xamarin

Im using Xamarin Studio on MacOS to build a Website using ASP.NET C#. Now i want to publish the project to my local IIS server, but I can't find that option. I want to publish the site and then copy the files to my IIS.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin Studio does not include Web Deploy or Publish Wizard. You have to copy the binaries and configure IIS manually.

Comment: minimal setup that worked for me: bin (folder), Views (folder) and global.asax (file)